# preg_replace - Replace data attributes with new values?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the data attribute data-note with new values for an array.

```
$ids = array(
    '111' => '999', // replace data-note=111 with data-note= 999
    '222' => '888' // replace data-note=222 with data-note= 888
);

$html = '<span data-note="111" data-type="comment" name="a b c">el for 111 </span> text <span data-note="222" data-type="comment">el for 222 </span>';

foreach($ids as $oldKey => $newKey) {
    $patterns[] = '/data-note="[' . $oldKey . ']/';
    $replacements[] = '/data-note="[^"' . $newKey . ']"/';
}

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $html); // echos ... /data-note="[^"999]"/11" ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is wrong, you forgot to write the error

Comment: for string replacement you should use str_replace instead of preg_replace. it's much easier for string only replacement, without the need of regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` are specail character in a regex, you have to escape them:

```
$patterns[] = '/data-note="\[' . $oldKey . '\]/';
```

Moreover I guess you want simply:

```
$patterns[] = '/data-note="' . $oldKey . '"/';
```

Change also the replacement part:

```
$replacements[] = 'data-note="' . $newKey . '"';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately, both those patterns return the original string with no changes.

Comment: @Cris: What is your expected result? The second one works for me unless you want other thing that `<span /data-note="[^"999]"/ ...` wich effectively produces an invalid html.

Comment: The end result should be <span data-note="999" ..... sorry I should have been more clear. The second one returns <span /data-note="999"/ (notice the extra slashes)